# onActivityResult returns null data for an Image Capture

Tags: android, onactivityresult

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    filePath = getOutputMediaFile(FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Uri output = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
    startActivityForResult(i, RETURN_FILE_PATH);
}

    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //data is always null here.
    //requestCode = RETURN_FILE_PATH;
    //resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK;
}
```

I checked the values for **file** and **output Uri**, both are fine and the captured **image actually exists at that location**.

But the data returned in `onActivityResult` is always `null` even after capturing the image.

**EDIT:**

I checked this question:

[onActivityResult returns with data = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231875/onactivityresult-returns-with-data-null?rq=1)

which says:

> Whenever you save an image by passing EXTRAOUTPUT with camera intent
>   the data parameter inside the onActivityResult always return null. So,
>   instead of using data to retrieve the image , use the filepath to
>   retrieve the Bitmap.

and maybe that solution will work for me. But the above code of mine was a working code until now for the same scenario.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10192956/1965084) data is null when you pre insert a uri. That means you already defined your output uri here:

```
  i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
```

So when you get a Activity.RESULT_OK; just load the taken photo by its known url.

Comment: Yeah just saw that post. But the same code worked for the past 6 months why all of a sudden now it behaves this way :(

Comment: Unfortunately i am not expert on this topic put what i guess that its a device specific functionality related to the hardware. This post mentions that there is a different behaviour on Samsung devices: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8248327/1965084

Answer (score 1):

Try this code this is working for me.

```
else if(requestCode == Constant.PICK_FROM_CAMERA)
            {

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    if(data!=null)
                    {
                        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                        //path= mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
                        try
                        {
                            path = getPath(mImageCaptureUri,Wonderlistpage.this); //from Gallery
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
                            Log.i("check image attach or not", e.toString());
                        }

                        String arr[] = path.split("/");
                        int i;
                        String k = null;
                        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                        {
                            k=arr[i];       
                        }
                        photoname="_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +k;
                         if(setprofileimage_sendimagewithmessage==1)
                         {
                             performCrop(mImageCaptureUri);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                              loading_details="CAMERA";
                              new performBackgroundTask33().execute();
                         }
                    }
                    else
                    {
file1  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "_FromCamera.jpg");

                        Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
                        try
                        {
                            path = getPath(mImageCaptureUri,Wonderlistpage.this); //from Gallery
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
                            Log.i("check image attach or not", e.toString());
                        }
                        String arr[] = path.split("/");
                        int i;
                        String k = null;
                        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                        {
                            k=arr[i];       
                        }
                        photoname="_"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +k;
                         if(setprofileimage_sendimagewithmessage==1)
                         {
                             performCrop(mImageCaptureUri);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                              loading_details="CAMERA";
                              new performBackgroundTask33().execute();
                         }

                    }

                    //new UploadTask().execute();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try following code*

```
        {
            final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
            Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
            imageCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                if (fullPath.contains("DCIM")) {

                    //get bitmap from fullpath here.
                    return;
                }
            }
            while (imageCursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Put this code into your onActivityResult. The same problem i have faced on some devices and this solved my problem. Hope this will also help you.

```
try {

    Uri selectedImage = output;

    if (selectedImage == null)
        return;

    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    return;
}
```

You will get the Picture path in **picturePath** variable and Uri in **selectedImage** Variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity has launchmode as singleInstance in your manifest then you would face this issue. Try changing it. As it cancels the result everytime.