# Camera NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Im working off the Android camera tutorial, SDK 11. For some reason I'm getting a Null Pointer within handleCameraPhoto(). The only thing I see is "Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity", but I can't sort out why.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

        ///Toast.makeText(this, "File Uri"+fileUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }   
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                handleCameraPhoto(data);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
                finish();
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed, quiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param intent
     */
    private void handleCameraPhoto(Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Shindiggy");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Shindiggy", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Error Cat

```
11-19 11:39:06.782: W/dalvikvm(7719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41549700)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.shindiggy.shindiggy/com.shindiggy.shindiggy.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at com.shindiggy.shindiggy.CameraActivity.handleCameraPhoto(CameraActivity.java:68)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at com.shindiggy.shindiggy.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:51)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-19 11:39:06.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7719):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your Intent parameter `data` is likely null.

Comment: Ok, so why would the Intent return null when the picture was successfully taken and should have been passed to onActivityResult() on camera Intent completion?

Comment: Please click near the answer that helped you solve the problem. You will be helping future visitors such as yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `handleCameraPhoto(asdf)` is being called with an argument in your code (but you haven't shown us this part), and the problem is that the object `asdf` was not allocated with `new`. That means that there's no physical object in the program's memory.

So when the instructions of the method are executed, more especifically `data.getData()`, the crash happens because the name `data` doesn't refer to a valid object in your program's memory.

**NullPointerException** errors happen when we try to access members of an object that was not allocated properly. **Make sure you allocate the object when calling `handleCameraPhoto()`.**

Comment: Updated the post to include handleCameraPhoto()

Comment: @Levi The implementation of `handleCameraPhoto()` was already there, now it is duplicated. What I meant is that you didn't show where `handleCameraPhoto()` is being called, because that is where the problem is.

Comment: Its being called within onActivityResult() the acting callback for the Intent, and basically just forward the Intent object to handleCameraPhoto(). Sorry if Im still not following

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when the phone is plugged into a USB cord, access to Camera files is blocked for security reasons. Also, check for null data when coming back to activity from Camera.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys, its helped me think of what I needed to look for.

> Whenever you save an image by passing EXTRAOUTPUT with camera intent
>   the data parameter inside the onActivityResult always return null. So,
>   instead of using data to retrieve the image , use the filepath to
>   retrieve the Bitmap.
>
> See [onActivityResult returns null data for an Image Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827460/onactivityresult-returns-null-data-for-an-image-capture)

So with that said, updated handleCameraPhoto to get the fileUri, and the app is back to working.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param intent
 */
private void handleCameraPhoto(Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
            this.fileUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```